# set date format dynamically using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting date and time from server from that i need to get date.

sometimes  "2015-04-20 11:40:05 Etc/GMT"and sometimes "2015-04-20T11:40:05Z"

so how to set date format dynamically?

below is my code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
NSDate *purchaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strPurchaseDate];
```

I want to set date format dynamically. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use NSDataDetector http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:

e.g. with current locale value ([NSLocale curentLocale]) or use [dateFormatter setLocale:...], specifying selected language

**NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];**

and **`[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:...]`** to set it t`NSDateFormatterShortStyle`, `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`, or `NSDateFormatterLongStyle`